How do I include damage in character motion？
I have been suffering from the same problem for several days. I want to add damage to the attack motion, but I can't solve this problem. Please lend me your wisdom.
public class BaseWeapon : MonoBehaviour
{
　　　　protected WeaponSpawnerStats stats;

　　　　protected void attactEnemy(Collider2D collider2d, float attack)
　　　　{
        
　　　　　　　　if(!collider2d.gameObject.TryGetComponent<EnemyController>(out var enemy)) return;
　　　　　　　　float damage = enemy.Damage(attack);
　　　　　　　　spawner.TotalDamage += damage;
        
　　　　　　　　if (0 > stats.HP) return;
　　　　　　　　stats.HP--;
　　　　　　　　if (0 > stats.HP) Destroy(gameObject);

　　　　protected void attackEnemy(Collider2D collider2d)
　　　　{
　　　　　　　　attackEnemy(collider2d, stats.Attack);
　　　　　　　　/*
　　　　　　　　BaseWeapon.cs(59,3): error CS1501: 
　　　　　　　　No overload for method 'attackEnemy' takes 2 arguments
　　　　　　　　*/
　
　　　}
}

protected void attackEnemy(Collider2D collider2d)
　　　　{
　　　　attackEnemy(collider2d);
　　　　}

It works, but the attack motion will not contain any damage

The method you are trying to call has a typo: it's called attactEnemy (t instead of k). Updating it to attackEnemy should fix the problem.
Your updated code attackEnemy(collider2d); doesn't cause a compilation error because you're calling the same method recursively. It doesn't do anything though (besides wasting resources), as the method just calls itself in a loop.

I have been suffering from this bug for a few days. Now I can only feel embarrassed by my immaturity. Thank you for kindly answering these beginner questions.

No problem! A strong IDE really reduces issues like this, e.g. I find Rider excellent for Unity (and it's free for non-commercial use now)

doesn't cause a compilation error because you're calling the same method recursively. It doesn't do anything though .. it will definitely cause a StackOverflowException on runtime
